# How to loop through the div to reset the delegate of the links in?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, session, delegates

If i have method like this to Draw my side Menu Dynamically :

```
private void DrawSideMenu()
{

    LinkButton x;
    TaskDTO TaskList = new TaskDTO();
    List<TaskDTO> List =   TaskList.DrawMenu(int.Parse(Session["emp"].ToString()));

    HtmlGenericControl myDIV = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    myDIV.ID = "menu8";
    HtmlGenericControl myOrderedList = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");//css clss for <ul>
    myOrderedList.ID = "orderedList";
    myOrderedList.Attributes.Add("class", "task");
    HtmlGenericControl listItem1;
    string count = "";
    foreach (TaskDTO i in List)
    {
        count = AdjustMenuCount1(i.TaskCode);
        x = new LinkButton();
        x.ID = i.TaskCode.ToString();
        x.Text = i.TaskName + "&nbsp; &nbsp;" + count;
        x.Click += new EventHandler(TaskC);
        x.Style["FONT-FAMILY"] = "tahoma";
        listItem1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        listItem1.Attributes.Add("class", "normal");
        if (count != "0")
        {
            listItem1.Controls.Add(x);
            myOrderedList.Controls.Add(listItem1);
        }
    }
    myDIV.Controls.Add(myOrderedList);
    MenuTD.Controls.Add(myDIV);
    Session["SideMenu"] = myDIV;//Save to redraw when page postbacks
}
```

---

This Method takes long time to draw my menu.so i call it one time in (`!IsPostBack`) and save it in session so that i could redraw it like that :

```
MenuTD.Controls.Add( ((System.Web.UI.Control)(Session["SideMenu"])));
```

It redraws it successfully but when i click on any link it doesn't hit the event because i thought it's not possible to save the `x.Click += new EventHandler(TaskC);` in the session ,so i want to know how to loop through my session content to resetting the delegate of my link ?

Comment: Honestly sounds like a terrible thing to do. What makes creating the menu slow and how slow exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That idea won't work because [if you're not wiring up the Event Handler every time the page is loaded, it won't run.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686413/eventhandler-and-postback-net)

If we come back to the original issue, you said it's slow. Creating controls at runtime cannot be slow and it's most likely the way you create your list of items:

```
List<TaskDTO> List = TaskList.DrawMenu(int.Parse(Session["emp"].ToString()));
```

Instead of storing complete menu, try to store in the Session only List and create all controls as usual. If menu is required on one page only, then use [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of Session.

Also it makes sense to change the entire code as currently you hardcode all style and layout settings in the code. Create all layout (div, ul, li) in aspx, move all styles in css (for example, you use "task" class but still set "tahoma" in the code). This would simplify the code and bring more flexibility.

```
List<TaskDTO> List = null;

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["List"] != null) {
        List = (List<TaskDTO>)ViewState["List"];
    } else {
       // ArrayList isn't in view state, so we need to load it from scratch.
        List = TaskList.DrawMenu(int.Parse(Session["emp"].ToString()));
    }

    // Code to create menu, e.g. 
    if (!Page.IsPosBack) {
        Repeater1.DataSource = List;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save PageArrayList before the page is rendered.
    ViewState.Add("List", List);
} 
...

<ul id="orderedList">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# Eval("TaskName") %></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Comment: I agree.  In the realm of controls, this one is extremely simple.  The problem is likely retrieving the data.  I'd first determine if that could be optimized (since your first page load will still be slow), and then consider storing it in the session or cache to improve performance on subsequent page loads if caching the data is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe save it in application level so it only gets built once, then just put the menu into an object and loop through it to re-add the clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that in order for it to work you are going to have to rebind the `Click` handler on every `Page_Load`.

Based on your code, and assuming your `TaskC` is available, you can make this method:

```
private void RebindMenuHandlers() {

    if(Session["SideMenu"] == null)
        return; // Your menu has not been built yet

    var menu = ((System.Web.UI.Control)(Session["SideMenu"]));

    var orderedList = menu.Controls[0];

    foreach(var listItem in orderedList){

        foreach(var control in listItem){
            var linkButton = control as LinkButton;
            if(linkButton != null){
                linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(TaskC);
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it on your Page_Load event:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RebindMenuHandlers();
    // .... etc
}
```

I just typed this directly here, so please forgive any silly compilation mistakes, this should be enough to give you the general idea. Hope that helps.